# java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed java mail

Tags: java, email, exception, gmail

**UPD***
issue seemed to be behind Windows firewall and/or antivirus problem, blocking the cport connecting, cause on Ubuntu I can connect to that port with no problem. I will investigate the cause and let you know what was blocking it. Special thanks to user **Perception** for helping me out!

Getting this exception when trying to send an email using gmail test account. 
Here is the mailing code

```
package Controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;


import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class C_New_Email {

    static int status;
    static File selectedFile;
    static String email = "coffeebrakeproject@gmail.com";
    static String password = "mypass"; // obviously I am using another one

    public static void sendMail (String toEmail, String subjectEmail, String textEmail) 
   {    


       Properties props = new Properties();
                  props.put("mail.smtp.user", email);
                  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                  props.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);
                  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
                  props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
                  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
                  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

       Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                                @Override
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(email, password);
                }
            });         
      try{
         session.setDebug(true);
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(toEmail));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject(subjectEmail);

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText(textEmail);

         MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
         textBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/plain");
         // Send message
         Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
         transport.connect ("smtp.gmail.com", 465, email, password);
         transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
         transport.close();  
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

    public static int returnStatus () {
        return status;
    }

    public static File returnFile () {
        return selectedFile;
    }

    public static void openFileChooser () {
        JFileChooser Attachments = new JFileChooser(".");
        status = Attachments.showDialog(Attachments, null);

        if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            selectedFile = Attachments.getSelectedFile();
        }
        else if (status == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            Attachments.setVisible(false);
            selectedFile = null;
        }

    }
}
```

here is the full error output

```
run:
Email clicked
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at Controller.C_New_Email.sendMail(C_New_Email.java:72)
    at View.V_New_Email.send_buttonActionPerformed(V_New_Email.java:158)
    at View.V_New_Email.access$000(V_New_Email.java:16)
    at View.V_New_Email$1.actionPerformed(V_New_Email.java:62)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:211)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 42 more
```

I have tried to google the issue with the similar problems
[java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247119/java-net-socketexception-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error)

But didn't get the idea how to fix mine anyway. Any tips?

Updated

if I change the port to 587 it fails to authenticate and gives me a plain text error

```
Email clicked
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL true
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at Controller.C_New_Email.sendMail(C_New_Email.java:72)
    at View.V_New_Email.send_buttonActionPerformed(V_New_Email.java:158)
    at View.V_New_Email.access$000(V_New_Email.java:16)
    at View.V_New_Email$1.actionPerformed(V_New_Email.java:62)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: Does the error occur consistently?

Comment: Hm, not entirely, for instance if I change the port, it shows completely different error. Want  me to include this into a head question?

Comment: An error would be expected if you used a different port, but it *would* be helpful to see which one you get in that case.

Comment: I've updates the question regarding different port.

Comment: You have quite a bit of unnecessary code mixed up, but it should still work (when using SSL, port 465). You might want to verify that you are not behind a (misconfigured) proxy (for example, does your network have a SOCKS server?).

Comment: As far as I know, I am not using any kind of proxy server at all. So I bet this is not an issue, however what and where should I check that I am not using proxy (any specific place)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27719/discussion-between-perception-and-nikki-kononov)